# Sampling from a rectangle with a need of a bias towards the center

Tags: python, statistics

I am currently sampling from a rectange [0, a] x [0, b] uniformly with this code:

```
import random

def uniform_sample(a, b):
    return [int(random.uniform(0, a), int(random.uniform(0, b)]
```

While this works, I am in need of a bias such that most of the points will be biased towards the center of the rectangle. How do I add such a sampling bias?

Comment: I guess one approach is that you can sample from a multivariate normal distribution centered at the center of your rectangle (a/2, b/2), and then remove points that falled outside of your rectangle. But there are a lot of other approaches and I think this question suits more to stats.stackexchange rather than here.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you! @TYZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to proceed is to generate the x's and the y's as you do now, and then apply a mapping (one for the xs and one for the ys).
We want the derivative of the inverse of this mapping to be somewhat peaked at the midpoint -- the more peaked the more the mapped points are biased towards the middle.

A family of functions that have this property is (sorry, I only write C, I hope it is comprehesible)

```
static  double  warp( double x, double a, double p)
{
double  c = 2.0*tanh( 0.5*p);
    return a*(0.5 + atanh( c*(x/a-0.5))/p);
}
```

Here x is your random sample, assumed to lie in [0,a], and p is a parameter; the bigger p is the more the mapped values will be biased towards the middle.

[image]

The image above was made by generating 100000 random samples in [0,2], warping them as above, and then binning (100 bins), and showing the percentages in each bin. The red line is the original uniform sample, the green line has warp parameter 2, the blue line parameter 4 and the pink line parameter 8.